# npm server closes when making a post request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express-jwt

I am following an course in mean stack and when I tried the authentication part by using a jwt token system and npm server started to close down each time I make a request. when I try to make a post request and store data in the db, data gets stored but right after that npm server closes.

code does not seem to be having any errors. works fine data gets stored and everything but npm server closes right after sending and request

message.js

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token)
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function(err, user){
        if (err){
            return res.status(500).json({
                title:'An error ocured',
                error:err
            });                
        }
        var message =new Message({
            content:req.body.content,
            user: user        
        });
        message.save(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title:'An error ocured',
                    error:err
                });
            }
            user.messages.push(result);
            user.save();

            res.status(201).json({
                message:'saved message',
                obj:result
            })
        })
 })
```

message.service.ts

```
addMessage(message:Message){
    
    const body = JSON.stringify(message);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        :'';
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message'+ token, body, {headers:headers})
        .map ((response : Response) =>  {
            const result=response.json()
            const message= new Message(result.obj.content,'Dummy',result.obj._id,null)
            this.messages.push(message)
            return message;
            
        } )
        
        .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

package.json

```
{
   "name": "nodejs-angular2",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www",
   "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config 
    webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && 
    ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -- 
    progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'assets/app/**/*.js' 
     'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.*'"
     },
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "^5.0.0",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"body-parser": "~1.15.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"debug": "~2.2.0",
"express": "~4.14.0",
"hbs": "~3.1.0",
"interpret": "^1.2.0",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"mongoose": "^5.5.5",
"mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
"morgan": "~1.6.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "^5.5.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.5"
},
 "devDependencies": {
"@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
"@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
"@types/node": "^6.0.45",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
"del-cli": "^0.2.0",
"html-loader": "^0.4.4",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
   }
  }
```

ERROR MESSAGES

> ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
>
> zone.js?fad3:3243 POST http://localhost:3000/message?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Im1lc3NhZ2VzIjpbXSwiX2lkIjoiNWNmMmUzYjRjNTdiMDQ0NDE4YWRjZmY5IiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoic2F0aGlyYSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoicGFzYW4iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCR0b3pBNm1kU0dnT04xNDBmV3BmQUZ1dDcvZTQyQjR5Y1NFRUxvWXNxbWlwaEJLaUtaWW1BaSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2F0aGlyYUBwYXNhbi5jb20iLCJfX3YiOjB9LCJpYXQiOjE1NTk0MjI3MDAsImV4cCI6MTU1OTQyOTkwMH0.gKHQmIszqLyQrR3g-PKLjqyJz9MFEgU4hKhTT6boFMA net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/